# Save JSON in Local Storage after the fetch

Tags: javascript, json, caching, fetch, local-storage

Sorry if this was posted a lot, I read through several articles but could not find the solution. So, I'm fetching a large `JSON` from this API, and I would like to cache the response somehow in the `localStorage`, so the next time the page loads, the scripts first checks if there is an object with the requested ID inside the `JSON`, and renders the content if there is one - and if there isn't, goes of to the API to fetch it.

I was thinking of setting up two fetch() functions, and this is what I have:

```
   fetch(url + id)
        .then((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem('myResponse', response);
        })              
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Then, check if there is something saved inside the `localStorage`, and if it is good, use it to render the HTML, if not, go on to another fetch to get it from the API.

```
  if(localStorage) {
     createHTML(localStorage.myResponse);
  } else {
     fetch(url + id)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => createHTML(data))
  }
```

But, in the first fetch, if I use `JSON.stringify(response)`, it just shows it as an empty object, so it the `localStorage` it looks like: `myResponse - {}`. If I do `console.log(response.json());` on the first fetch, it shows `Promise {<pending>}`.

I've tried to make something out of that, but without results...any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json()` is a Promise, it needs to be either `await`ed, or chained a `.then()`; If you simply log it as is, all you'll get is `Promise  {<pending>}` because it hasn't resolved yet.

```
fetch(url + id)
        .then( response => response.json() )
        .then( json => {
            localStorage.setItem('myResponse', JSON.stringify(json));
        })
```

Or with the async/await syntax :

```
const response = await fetch(url + id);
const json = await response.json();
localStorage.setItem('myResponse', JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: Thank you, ok so now my localStorage looks like this: myResponse - [object Object]. How can I use that later in my if statement..?

Comment: Ah, you just need to stringify it, updated my answer. If you don't, you are actually storing the string `"[object Object]"`, so it is useless

Comment: Ahhh...so I need the first .then to turn the response into the JS object with response.json(), (API url shows the JSON in my browser, not sure why I then need to run that method exactly - I guess it's made readable that way to the JS?).  Anyway, when that data is converted to the JS object, I need one more .then(json => localStor...) to "Stringify" it - so it's converted one more time to the JSON-like format, which can be saved into the localStorage? Did I get it right? Thanks a ton, this took me hours to make it working!

Comment: I would recommend dropping the `.then()` syntax, because it's an absolute pain to deal with, and go `async/await` all the way, which is basically asynchronous code written like sync code. It's so much nicer and easier to read, deal with and debug.